# Pop up menu that closes when I don't hold it in css active class

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigationbar

I made a collapsible menu, I call my active code with jQuery. However, it only appears when I hold the mouse, it disappears the moment I don't hold.

CSS

```
#menu{position: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left:-400px;
    background: linear-gradient(#1a0000, #800000);
}
#menu:active{
    left:0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.icon').click(function(){
            $('.icon').toggleClass('active');
            $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
        })
    })
```

Comment: I think you mean `#menu.active{left:0;}` rather than `#menu:active{left:0;}`.

Comment: that solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery for this.

Simply use the checkbox hack.

HTML

```
<div class="button">
  <input type="checkbox" id="open">
  <label for="open">click to open me
    <div class="menu">
      This is your menu that appears
    </div>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  This is your menu that appears
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button input {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

#open:checked+label>.menu {
  display: block !important;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8rmw40o2/)